# Keep focus on keyboard even when taped outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, keyboard

Hello guys I'm making a simple game and I'm using virtual keyboard on mobile for users to type letters. What I want is that keyboard doesn't disappear from screen when taped outside of it. Also I'm basically hiding my input outside of screen with CSS.I've tried using blur to achieve this but couldn't make it work. This is part of my code:

```
$('#gameContent').append("<input type='text' id='dummy'>");
$("#dummy").css({"position":"fixed","left":"120%"}).focus();
$(document).on("tap", keepFocus);

function keepFocus(){
    $(document).find("#dummy").focus();
}
```

You can see see full code live here http://www.wpacademy.nextweb.space/TestingMobile10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody ever has the same problem with the help of [Louys Patrice Bessette](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2159528/louys-patrice-bessette) this has solved my problem:
Timeout is necessary in my function to make it reappear automatically. Probably because there is an "animation" to make the keyboard appear.

```
function keepFocus(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(document).find("#dummy").focus();
    },100);
}
```

and `touchstart` should be used instead of `tap`, because tap will fail on iOS platform.

```
$(document).on("touchstart", keepFocus);
```